# VB6--COM Interop--C#(VS2019) SQL query timeout When calling two tables. with a join

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb6, com-interop

> VB6--COM Interop--C#(VS2019) SQL query timeout

I've a .NET DLL which makes calls to SQL-Server. It's been in production for several years. 
It is used by VB6 apps, C# Windows apps, SSIS processes. 
It is Registered for COM Interop to work with the old applications.

I have function in the C# DLL which retrieves data from a SQL Server table and feeds a class object.  I have added a JOIN to the Select statement.

To test, I call the modified process(DLL project) from a .Net Windows project.  The modified SQL query executes just fine.

But calling from COM Interop, modified process Times out.  It times out even when I create separate calls to the database.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

This is VB6-COM Wrapper DLL--COMInterOp--C#.Net DLL.  The overall process has been working fine and is now failing with this minor change to one function. If I undo the change, the function works again. i.e. if I revert to using only one table in my query it works.

Yes, I tested the query. And keep in mind, the modified query works fine when called from a separate .NET project used to test the functions in the DLL project.

Thanks for your input. I'll have to go to MSFT if I don't get any pointers here.

Comment: Yes you really need to add more specifc details. Very unlikely anyone can help you without that.

Comment: Compare a profiler trace of a working & non-working query looking for any differences in the flags/options that are set when the connection is established.